# MATLAB Image thresholding Issue

Tags: image, matlab, analysis, imread, image-thresholding

I have the following image that I am attempting to analyse, the idea is to outline the droplet so that I can then get its boundaries using bwboundaries.

[image: Original Image]

My code is currently

```
image = imread('IMG00022.jpg');

BW = im2bw(image, 0.35);
BW = ~BW;
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
```

which results in the following output. It includes the edges around the droplet that are of similar colour to the border.

[image: Current Output]

The goal is to achieve the below output. How can I go about rectifying this problem? Is the solution to use a threshold range rather than a static value (I am not sure if this would even resolve the issue) or is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Goal Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small [opening](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) will get you where you need to be:

```
se = strel('disk',11);
BW = imopen(BW,se);
```

Adjust the size (11) to what you need to get everything except the droplet removed.